# Opening new activity from base activity

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, onclicklistener, android-toolbar

I have a base activity which holds toolbar that I need all over my activities. The toolbar consists of a `textView` on it. I need to handle click listener on that `textView` and open my `MainActivity`. I am not able to achieve it.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   private Toolbar toolbar;
   private TextView txtLogin;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      init();
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
         case R.id.profile_image:
           startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
           break;

         case R.id.txtLogin:
           startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
           break;
      }
   }

   public void setUpToolbar() {
     toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

     txtLogin = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
     txtLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
}
```

I am calling my `setUpToolbar()` method from my MainActivity.

Comment: Why are you not using Fragments?

Comment: post your code where you are calling `setUpToolbar()` in MainActivity

Comment: I am calling it after setContentView () in MainActivity

Comment: What are u using this base activity for? If it is a "base activity" and it holds a toolbar that you want to use in all other activities, then just make other activities extend this base activity.